# Why was this NAA flag declined

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

In [Controller can't receive model data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39785803/controller-cant-receive-model-data/39788893#39788893), OP is asking specifically

> My question is why controller can't receive the model data from View in my project?
>
> Please explain why this error was caused and how to solve it.

and included their code. The answer by Ajay shows one option to solve the issue but contains some errors (*IEnumerables and binding don't play very nicely directly out of the box* is incorrect) so I dupe hammered the question to an answer which explains the issue in more detail.

I then flagged OP's 'self answer' with a NAA flag. The reason was that it's just some alternative code the OP tried, which not only does not work, it makes no attempt to answer the actual question. The OP subsequently copied the alternative code into [this new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39789439/complex-model-binding) which I also dupe hammered.

The flag was declined with

> It's an answer. It also contains a new question, but it's still an answer

Did I flag this incorrectly?

Comment: As someone with no experience in that area, and the way the answer opens with "I used the stupid way to achieve my goal.", it would seem to me like the user solved their problem, and was posting their solution. Just sayin', that's how it reads. A custom flag with details would probably be better, but I can't say if a mod would actually end up deleting.

Comment: Nah, it looks to me to be part of the question. Something like, "here's something I tried, but it's not good enough. How do I solve this?" If it's an answer, it's a very bad one, and in the least should be down-voted.

Comment: I'm leaning towards non-answer, or at least fatally VLQ, deleted for now. [Screenshot for posterity](http://i.stack.imgur.com/C6fxw.png). I can see arguments either way.

Comment: Instead of declining, how about editing out the "new question" instead?

Comment: Can we change the flag name already? There are so many problems related to this. Many meta hours of discussion because of a poorly named flag with a specific flag that is incomprehensible without reading a book of a meta answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**TL;DR** I declined that flag because the answer at issue *is* an answer; it's just a bad one that also includes an off-topic new question. The off-topic, new-question part is not an answer, but the rest of it is. Whether or not it's a *correct* answer is not the issue.

## The Answer in Question

The OP's answer was just this:

> Hi I used the stupid way to achieve my goal. Can you help me to improve my code ?
>
> [giant MVC code blobs]

So, OP "used the stupid way to achieve [OP's] goal." In other words, the goal was achieved, the question was answered (even if in a "stupid way"), and everybody's theoretically at least a little happier than they were. The important thing is that OP's self-answer *tried* to answer the question.

*At least, that's how I read it.* It's certainly possible that OP meant, "This is the busted code I should have included in the question itself; this is what I need help with." But that's not how I read it. Before I'm willing to nuke content—and I do nuke a lot of it—it needs to be pretty clear that it's not constructive. This looks to me like a solution, even if a bad one, rather than part of the question.

## NAA Flags, SO Philosophy, and Such

Now, let's look at the rationale for your flag in this question:

> I then flagged OP's 'self answer' with a NAA flag. The reason was that it's just some alternative code the OP tried, which not only **does not work**, it **makes no attempt to answer the actual question**. The OP subsequently copied the alternative code into this new question which I also dupe hammered.

(emphasis added). When moderators look at flags, we're not looking for whether the answer is correct and contains working code. In fact, one standard reason we decline flags is:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

When you raise a NAA flag, you're saying, "This isn't an answer *at all* - it's completely irrelevant, spam, a new question, a thank you, or something else that doesn't even *try* to answer the question." We review the flag accordingly.

In terms of the famous post [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), a NAA flag is appropriate for the orange, not the half-eaten or rotten apples.

[image]

## So, What Happened Here?

When I looked at your flag, I didn't look to see if the new code works. That would require me to do one of two things: (1) read all of it and look for errors, or (2) fire up a VM, fire up Visual Studio, and drop in the code to look for problems that way. That's not what a NAA flag is for, and, frankly, we don't have nearly enough time to do that kind of deep-dive analysis on every answer that gets a flag.

The post doesn't look at all like "it makes no attempt to answer the actual question," to borrow your phrase. It looks like an attempt to answer it, at least partially: an attempt that could use improvement (and explicitly asked for it), but an attempt nonetheless.

You mentioned that OP copied the code into a new question. Okay, so be it. That doesn't mean it can't be an answer to the original question. And as you probably know, people copy and paste code from SO answers into new SO questions all the time. In any case, I don't know about that new question from looking at a simple "not an answer" flag.

What I saw was, effectively, "I used the stupid way to achieve my goal. Here are the code blobs I used. Can anyone make them better?" That is, an answer, but not a great one, with a new question tacked on. The answer may be "stupid," in OP's words, but it's still an answer. So, I wrote:

> It's an answer. It also contains a new question, but it's still an answer.

And there you have it.

Comment: See also: [How should we deal with an answer that answers the question, then follows up with another question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116951/how-should-we-deal-with-an-answer-that-answers-the-question-then-follows-up-wit)

Comment: To clarify, I did not flag it because the 'answer' was incorrect, or because OP included another question in it. I considered it an orange, not a half eaten rotting apple, in the same way I would consider _Ride a bike instead_ is not an answer to _Which bus to I catch to X_. But I accept that the mods do not have time to look at the code.

Comment: But ... sometimes "ride a bike" is a good answer; e.g. if there is no bus going to X today.

Comment: IMHO, unless totally ask for new problem instead of giving solution, the answer is still an answer, even with additional question embedded inside since the answer may partially solve OP's problem. However on my POV, better for OP to ask embedded question as a new problem, and place a link to his previous question. NAA rules apply if the answer just asking new problem or requesting for real answer without any attempts/efforts to solve existing problem.

Comment: Answers shouldn't contain question marks. The "answer" doesn't say _how_ it fixes the problem, and it contains a new question for general code review. It rather seems like a follow-up question than an attempt to answer. Seems like a rotten orange to me.

Comment: @Lundin It may be rotten, but it's a rotten apple still. Adding a question doesn't necessarily mean it's not useful as an answer. For example, could you salvage it by rewording it? If so, then it's probably an answer.

Comment: @Lundin the code he posted does attempt to solve his issue though, so in that case it is an answer. However, it does not explain *how* it fixes it, so it is VLQ, indeed. So to me it appears to be a rotten apple with a follow-up question. The thing with the close reasons, and even with the apple-orange situation is that they're open for interpretation. Shog9 made a great attempt to clarify it all, but now we're no longer discussing the answer, but we're discussing whether or not it's an orange, so I think the confusion is still there.

Comment: To me, it seems that the answer is more of a question/comment of the nature "this is a bad solution that shouldn't be used - I'll post it to bump the question for more attention". At any rate, it has been deleted an SO is a better site without it.

Comment: Extremely borderline this one. I can see arguments both ways and have no problem with how this scenario played out. FWIW.

Comment: Great answer! I particularily like the visual metaphores you used. Chapeau!