# Why was a NAA-flag on an answer linking to another SO answer declined?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, declined-flags, not-an-answer

Yesterday I flagged this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6169120/7666442 as not an answer, but my flag was declined

[image: Flag result summary showing "declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence..."]

Here is the screenshot of that answer

[image: Screenshot of answer linked above]

in that answer it's just saying there is broadcast receiver and has a link to another Stack Overflow post.

I've already read [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)

and that answer says

### What To Flag

> Links to an answer

In the answer I flagged there is link at the end.

> The answer can be found over here:

In the answer I flagged there is link to other post about the same problem.

What is the reason that my flag was declined?

Here are some other posts about *Why this NAA-flag is declined?* I visited but didn't understand why my flag was declined.

- [Why was this NAA flag declined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335586/7666442)
- [Why was my NAA flag declined?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290133/7666442)
- [Yet another "Why was my NAA-flag declined?" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320922/7666442)

Comment: Dammed if they do, dammed if they don't. Too many messages complaining when moderators **do not** delete stuff, and too many messages complaining when they **do** delete stuff. Or even close. At least they are getting paid with piles of gold and jewels, otherwise nobody would want the job.

Comment: At first glance, it's an accepted, "highly" upvoted answer, I'm not surprised a mod decline the NAA flag (by mistake since they just had this first glance handling 100 of flags). My advice would be to custom flag these answers, explaining that it's just a link to another SO question (which is already targeted in duplicate)

Comment: It's the same old shtick - it's an attempt to answer any question. That severely lowers the chance that an NAA flag is going to be accepted. The best you can do is downvote.

Comment: @yivi you jest, but actually moderators don't delete enough stuff. They delete less than review https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296609/792066 People complaining that moderators delete too much, will complain no matter how little they delete.

Comment: BTW, I would have left the "see here" part of the answer. That way, there's no way someone would be mislead thinking there's an answer anywhere on that post.

Comment: With the Q now being closed as a dupe, the answer seems useless.  Deleting it now wouldn't cause any loss of information or rep so we should probably just get rid of it.

Comment: *Technically*, if you strip the markup, there is a little, tiny speck of useful information. It's an extremely low quality answer, yes, but it is still an answer.

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain so, what it isn't an answer? The post of Shog was clear that this isn't an apple.

Comment: @Braiam if the answer was posted with only the second sentence, that would undoubtedly be a non-answer. I think the answer qualified for VLQ, but it was an honest attempt at an answer, and it contained a very tiny bit of information, so I don't disagree with the NAA flag being declined.

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain I have done an honest attempt to discuss constructively with you. Does that mean that I've actually discussed constructively with you from your point of view? Most of the time "honest attempt" isn't enough to qualify as actual answer. Heck, who can actually say they are even attempting to answer the question but instead attempting to rack reputation? I prefer working with stuff I can measure. This thing, shouldn't be considered an answer under any circumstance, even if it's posted on the answer box.

Comment: @Braiam I disagree. I did not say the attempt was what made it an answer. It contained a very tiny bit of information. I agree with its deletion and the flag being declined. While the answer was very, very low quality, it was still an answer.

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain are you aware that you are contraditing yourself? How do you expect someone to delete this answer if it doesn't get flagged?

Comment: @Braiam my point is that the VLQ flag was appropriate, NAA was not (but very nearly).

Comment: The irony here is that this answer couldn't be posted today: it'd be converted to a comment. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98950/answer-appears-automatically-converted-as-a-comment

Comment: @Shog9 That's weird, I've posted several answers linking to other answers/questions... Of course, they were very long answers, not link-only stuff

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This flag should not have been rejected. The answer is bad in several ways:

- It is a link-only answer. This is something that either a NAA or a VLQ flag should cover. It's not obvious to anyone which of the two that cover link-only answers - thus flag reviewer needs to have this in mind. This is enough to warrant a delete.
- The link goes to another SO post. This means that the question shouldn't have been answered in the first place, but closed as a duplicate.

It doesn't matter if "they attempted to answer the question" (which they didn't) - the answer should be deleted because of any of the two reasons above. NAA reviewers are supposed to check where links go.

---

Unrelated to the flag, there are other answers posted that may be valuable - I can't tell. At this point, it is not obvious if this question should be closed as a dupe, or the other one linked to, or if they should be merged. Or maybe it is all outdated information.

This is exactly why [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) gold badger users should moderate this, before anyone else. You are one such user, so we'll trust your judgement when closing this as a dupe. Though when it comes to posts with these many up-votes, it might be a good idea to bring it up on meta first.

Comment: Sorry, I can't upvote this. Not only is this not a link-only answer (it is ALMOST one). The second bullet is more to the point, dupes should not be answered. However a question being a dupe is not an argument to delete existing answers. The answer being bad is a reason though.

Comment: @Gimby And yet nobody will be able to provide a rationale why an answer which is nothing but a link to another SO question should be preserved.

Comment: Agreed completely. ["It's interesting to me that no one ever seems to try to defend answers like these except by resort to 'the rules'. Not for any actual value they hold."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350908/neutralizing-the-propaganda-effects-of-terrible-inaccurate-comments-on-wrongly/350917#comment483572_350917)

Comment: BTW, it was a moderator declined reason, rather that a review one.

Comment: @Braiam All the more reason to be careful when reviewing.

Comment: This answer is not NAA. It's clearly an attempt to answer. Even without link it's an answer and was helpful to question OP who didn't even know how to achieve needed. Link is a bonus, maybe even added within grace time. VLQ - yes, NAA - nope. *"This is something that either a NAA or a VLQ flag should cover"* - is wrong, don't misuse flags. Moderator doesn't have to be an expert so identifying question as "attempt to answer" (without checking links, is it SO, correctness of answer, etc.) is enough to decline flag and move on.

Comment: Two non-duplicate questions can have the same answer, so the second bullet is not necessarily correct. (It might be in this situation, I've not bothered trying to find the questions; but as a general rule of thumb it is not.)

Comment: Sometimes "_there's a broadcast receiver for connectivity changes_" is all you really need to point you down the right path. This WAS an answer. Not a gold standard answer, but it qualifies.

Comment: The NAA flag doesn't really provide much guidance here. I would have had to go to the actual post to figure out what the problem was, and NAA flags are supposed to be easier to dispatch than this (NAA being things that are... well, *not answers;* things like comments, new questions, etc., posted in the answer space.  NAA was never meant to flag *bad answers.*  Alas, this point seems to be lost on many people.)

Comment: As to your point about "NAA reviewers should check where the link goes..."  Why?  If I see an NAA flag, I expect to see something there *other than an attempt to answer.*  Where a rogue link goes (on something that is not supposed to be an attempt to answer in the first place) is not particularly relevant.  The question you need to ask yourself when you're flagging for moderator attention is: *"are you effectively communicating your intent?"*

Answer (score 6):

I freely admit that sometimes the standards are fairly loose on NAA/LQP, but [the principles for both are](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

1. Attempts to answer the question
2. Does not make you view a link to get said answer (i.e. remove the link and it still meets #1)

I think we can agree we've met #1, but what about #2? The full answer is

> There's a broadcast receiver for connectivity changes. See [here]

The answer then links to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767591/check-intent-internet-connection) where we find out that `BroadcastReceiver` is a *thing* in Android/Java. So the answer could be rewritten as

> Use `BroadcastReceiver`. Here's a [link] to how

Now this is not a **good** answer, but it still qualifies as an answer. As such, **it should not be deleted as NAA**. You should use up/down votes to handle this. We see this in effect because this answer is +22/-6 but the next answer (which explains why and how to use this class) is +95/-0

Comment: Rather, we see this in effect because it is an old post pre-dating the link-only answer policy. And any old, high-attention answer tends to attract up-votes over time. It is enough to conclude that 1) the answer is crap, and 2) as such it should be deleted from the site. Review policies be damned. _We do not need to preserve crap_ is the policy that overrules all others.

Comment: @Lundin Don't confuse "Should we delete this?" with "Is this NAA?". If it were negative score, I'd be inclined to 20k delete vote it (and maybe a mod flag would succeed in that regard). But we shouldn't use NAA to delete answers that aren't good. That opens a giant can of worms.

Comment: If we delete crap flagged as NAA, the crap gets deleted from the site. If we don't, the crap remains on the site. Those are the two possible consequences. No can of worms here.

Comment: It is not a NAA because it might be an answer after editing it? That can be said of any link-only answer.

Comment: @Goyo Not really. There's no way to fix an answer that is solely `This [link] has your answer` (which is what most NAA are). That was the [point Shog9 made a long time ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: Of course you can do the same, follow the link, learn that `BroadcastReceiver` is a thing and edit the answer `Use a BroadcastReceiver as explained in this [link]`..

Comment: @Goyo remember that there's the option to "edit" in the low quality posts review queue. While we could try to savage whatever we can find useful, this post lack of any of said usefulness for us to spend time into the task of savaging.

Comment: tbh a broadcast receiver is not a `BroadcastReceiver`. Without the link I'm still lost what I should be looking for. The answer is NAA no matter how loose you interpret the vague rules that are here and nowhere on MSO.